# Rails app can run locally, but cannot deploy in Heroku website. Heroku shows The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I'm very new to rails. I want to deploy my Rails app to Heroku account. The rails app runs fine locally, but if I go to Heroku web(By clicking domain in Heroku account: https://naomis-sample-app.herokuapp.com/), it shows [The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.][1]

Then I run

```
    heroku logs
```

I find

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

Then I run

```
    rake routes
```

to show the routes I set up.

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    root GET  /                                 application#hello
    static_pages_home GET  /static_pages/home(.:format) static_pages#home
    static_pages_help GET  /static_pages/help(.:format) static_pages#help
```

Then I run

```
    heroku run rake routes
```

it shows

You don't have any routes defined!
Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

I try to run

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate
```

But it not work.

Can somebody help me with this?

Here is some of my code:

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
        root 'application#hello'

        get 'static_pages/home'

        get 'static_pages/help'

    end
```

application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        protect_from_forgery with: :exception

        def hello
            render html: "Hello!"
        end
    end
```

in my Gemfile
I put gem 'sqlite3' under development and test group.

gem 'pg' under production

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
      repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
      "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
    end


    gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
    gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'

    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.2', group: :doc

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3'
      gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13.0'
      gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.14'
      gem 'mini_backtrace', '~> 0.1.3'
      gem 'guard-minitest', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.6'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
      gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
    end
```

I also run bundle install --without production

Thanks

Comment: Did you pushed your code to heroku with `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Also make sure you're on master or you might need to push it with `git push heroku your_branch:master`

Comment: I try this, everything is up-to-date. BTW,  locally, I'm in static-pages branch. Do I need to merge everything to master first?

Comment: Solved!!!! By merging everything to master.